# Python: how to play video using python and tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have few video files that I would like to play when I click a button in the tkinter window. Preferably in VLC or in the Tkinter window itself if possible.

I'm using mac.

Tried pip installing VLC and os.startfile. Tried most of the solutions provided here in stackoverflow.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()
def video(): 
   os.startfile('FILENAME')
vid = tk.Button(root, text="play", bg='gray', command=video)
vid.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dumb question, but you are on Windows os? (os.startfile only works on windows according to doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Comment: Ah ok! I'm on mac. Sorry should have mentioned that